# Count string beginning by x, and store in Array Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, regex, json

I made a regex in String which is storing JSON Data, I could find all images in my JSON Data :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]*>");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contentString.toString());
        while(matcher.find()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "MATCHER : "+ matcher.group());
        }
```

Returns :

```
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/april-13.jpg'>
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/10501752_10152650053307000_6249740615573255728_n1.jpg'>
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.xcweather.co.uk/">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.windguru.cz/int/index.php?sc=103244">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.xcweather.co.uk/">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.buoyweather.com/wxnav6.jsp?region=UK&program=nww3BW1&grb=nww3&latitude=55.0&longitude=-8.75&zone=0&units=e">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://magicseaweed.com/Bundoran-Surf-Report/50/">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://magicseaweed.com/UK-Ireland-MSW-Surf-Charts/1/">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.marine.ie/Home/site-area/data-services/marine-forecasts/wave-forecasts">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://magicseaweed.com/Bundoran-Surf-Report/50/">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://magicseaweed.com/UK-Ireland-MSW-Surf-Charts/1/">
04-13 16:33:57.279    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.marine.ie/Home/site-area/data-services/marine-forecasts/wave-forecasts">
04-13 16:33:57.280    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/13000">
04-13 16:33:57.280    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.met.ie/">
04-13 16:33:57.280    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/13000">
04-13 16:33:57.280    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.met.ie/">
04-13 16:33:57.280    3642-3657/jardelcompany.bundoransurfco I/MainActivity﹕ MATCHER : <a href="http://www.irishtimes.com/weather/tides.html">
```

But now I would like to count the number of links beginning by "`<a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery-113]"`" and store his href link in Array...

Do you have any idea ?
Cheers!

Comment: Are you asking how to make that regex, or how to store matches in an array, or both?

Comment: In `contentString.toString()` if `contentString` is String, then `toString()` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be parsing HTML with regex but with proper parser. There are many reasons for this like fact that

- order of attributes like `rel` and `href` can change so you could see elements like `<a href="..." rel="">` which could be easily skipped if your regex will describe `<a rel="..." href="...">`.
- attributes don't need to be surrounded with `"` but with `'` which creates additional risk of skipping important data.

I like using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) so here is example with this library:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlText);
Elements relLinks = doc.select("a[rel]");
//or if you want rel only with "prettyPhoto[gallery-113]" use
//Elements relLinks = doc.select("a[rel=prettyPhoto[gallery-113]]");//
System.out.println("number of `rel`: "+relLinks.size());
for (Element el : relLinks){
    System.out.println(el.attr("href"));
}
```

Output:

```
number of `rel`: 2
http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/april-13.jpg
http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/10501752_10152650053307000_6249740615573255728_n1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just want to skip **[** and **]** in your regular expression.

so you could do something like this:

```
<a rel="prettyPhoto\[gallery-113\]"[^>]*>
```

in java you need to modify it as :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a rel=\"prettyPhoto\\[gallery-113\\]\"[^>]*>");     // note the skip character ( \ ) before " and \
```

**EDIT:**

To store them in lets say in `arrayList,` all you need to do is to create a new `arraylist` object:

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
```

then within your `loop` add this line:

```
list.add(matcher.group());
```

Comment: Nice regular expression !!! Thanks :) And now, if I want to store href's url in Array, how can I make that ? :)

Answer (score 0):

To add matches to an array:

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while(matcher.find()) {
        matches.add(matcher.group()); // or whatever you want to add
    }

String[] array = matches.toArray();
String[] differentWay = matches.toArray(new String[matches.size()]);
```

Or I think this will also work:

```
String[] matches = new String[matcher.groupCount()];
index = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
        matches[index] = matcher.group();
        index++;
    }
```